# Label dynamic text but also shorten it to only 50 characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dynamic-text

I am using dynamic text and labeling this:

`<dyn type="page" property="number"/>`

but I only want it to label the first 50 characters and than if it has to shorten the name to than put `et al.` at the end.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to add an attachment or image? Also, can you provide additional context and information to your question. It isn't all that clear.

Comment: Try adding a field to your DDP index layer, use a cursor or the field calculator to apply a string manipulation, and then use the new field in a dynamic text element.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because the answer to that shows how to use any field in the DDP layer attribute table with dynamic text.  Your new and more focussed question to research/ask may then be how to manipulate the field values in the name field to become what you want to see labelled (which will be Python manipulated in the new field).